# How to swipe one row of RecyclerView programatically (at run time)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with items inside like this:

[image]

I use `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to listen for swipe and onChildDraw() to draw a canvas when items are swiped:

[image]

A bit more swipe:

[image]

## My problem:

I want to simulate a swipe (at run time) just on first item inside the list of items; I need first item to go (more or less ) -100 px on its X axis and then go back to original position. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

I created some utility method in case someone needs it

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

/**
 * @author Oleh Haidaienko
 * @since 29.07.2020
 */
object SwipeUtils {
    /**
     * Programmatically swipe RecyclerView item
     * @param recyclerView RecyclerView which item will be swiped
     * @param index Position of item
     * @param distance Swipe distance
     * @param direction Swipe direction, can be [ItemTouchHelper.START] or [ItemTouchHelper.END]
     * @param time Animation time in milliseconds
     */
    fun swipeRecyclerViewItem(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        index: Int,
        distance: Int,
        direction: Int,
        time: Long
    ) {
        val childView = recyclerView.getChildAt(index) ?: return
        val x = childView.width / 2F
        val viewLocation = IntArray(2)
        childView.getLocationInWindow(viewLocation)
        val y = (viewLocation[1] + childView.height) / 2F
        val downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(
            MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                downTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                x,
                y,
                0
            )
        )
        ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, distance).apply {
            duration = time
            addUpdateListener {
                val dX = it.animatedValue as Int
                val mX = when (direction) {
                    ItemTouchHelper.END -> x + dX
                    ItemTouchHelper.START -> x - dX
                    else -> 0F
                }
                recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(
                    MotionEvent.obtain(
                        downTime,
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
                        mX,
                        y,
                        0
                    )
                )
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This extension functions could help you:

```
fun ViewGroup.performSwipeToLeft(target: View, distance: Float) {
    this.performSwipe(target, distanceX = -distance, distanceY = 0f)
}
fun ViewGroup.performSwipeToRight(target: View, distance: Float) {
    this.performSwipe(target, distanceX = +distance, distanceY = 0f)
}

fun ViewGroup.performSwipe(target: View, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float) {
    val parentCoords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    this.getLocationInWindow(parentCoords)

    val childCoords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    target.getLocationInWindow(childCoords)

    val initGlobalX = childCoords[0].toFloat() + 1f
    val initGlobalY = childCoords[1].toFloat() + 1f

    val initLocalX = (childCoords[0] - parentCoords[0]).toFloat() + 1f
    val initLocalY = (childCoords[1] - parentCoords[1]).toFloat() + 1f

    val downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
    var eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

    this.dispatchTouchEvent(
        MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            initGlobalX,
            initGlobalY,
            0
        ).apply {
            setLocation(initLocalX, initLocalY)
            source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        }
    )

    val steps = 20
    var i = 0
    while (i in 0..steps) {
        val globalX = initGlobalX + i * distanceX / steps
        val globalY = initGlobalY + i * distanceY / steps
        val localX = initLocalX + i * distanceX / steps
        val localY = initLocalY + i * distanceY / steps
        if (globalX <= 10f || globalY <= 10f) {
            break
        }
        this.dispatchTouchEvent(
            MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                ++eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
                globalX,
                globalY,
                0
            ).apply {
                setLocation(localX, localY)
                source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
            }
        )
        i++
    }

    this.dispatchTouchEvent(
        MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            ++eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            initGlobalX + i * distanceX,
            initGlobalY + i * distanceY,
            0
        ).apply {
            setLocation(initLocalX + i * distanceX, initLocalY + i * distanceY)
            source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        }
    )
}
```

In your case you could use this as follows:

```
recylerView.performSwipeToLeft(recyclerView.getChildAt(0), 100f)
```

Comment: This works flawlessly for my case. It is weird that ItemTouchHelper does not provide anything to mock the swipes for showing to the user. This comes handy for that.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could achieve that with `RecyclerView` by simply registering `DataObserver` for your `Adapter` which will notify you when an item has been removed, inserted or changed. lets consider this scenario

```
    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
             adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(this);//unregister the adapter since no longer needed.
        }
    });
```

in above code will notify you  when an item has been inserted you could then use `recyclerView.getChildAt(0).translateX(-100);` to simulate the swipe and simply   `recyclerView.getChildAt(0).translateX(0);` to `reposition` the `X` of the `view` back within the method `onChanged()`.