# Mimic swipe right or left programmatically respecting overrided onChildDraw in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my app I have a recyclerView runeListRecyclerView. I have implemented swipes left and right with changing background color and drawing corresponding icon on swipe.

```
// implement swipes:
    val myCallback = object: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                swipeMagusAction(mMagusViewModel, viewHolder.adapterPosition, "success")
            } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                swipeMagusAction(mMagusViewModel, viewHolder.adapterPosition, "fail")
            }
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.adapterPosition);
        }

        override fun onChildDraw(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {
            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                var icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.failure_icon)
                var iconLeft = 0
                var iconRight = 0
                val background: ColorDrawable
                val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
                    val dip = 16f
                    val r: Resources = resources
                val margin = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                        dip,
                        r.displayMetrics
                    ).toInt()
                val iconWidth = icon!!.intrinsicWidth
                val iconHeight = icon.intrinsicHeight
                val cellHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top
                val iconTop = itemView.top + (cellHeight - iconHeight) / 2
                val iconBottom = iconTop + iconHeight
                var actionHintText: String = ""
                val actionHintTextView: TextView

                // Right swipe.
                if (dX > 0) {
                    icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.failure_icon)
                    icon?.setTint(Color.BLACK)
                    background = ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.failure))
                    background.setBounds(itemView.left, itemView.top, (itemView.left + dX).toInt(), itemView.bottom)
                    iconLeft = margin
                    iconRight = margin + iconWidth
                } /*Left swipe.*/ else if (dX < 0) {
                    icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.success_icon)
                    icon?.setTint(Color.BLACK)
                    background = ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.success))
                    background.setBounds((itemView.right - dX).toInt(), itemView.top, (itemView.right + dX).toInt(), itemView.bottom)
                    iconLeft = itemView.right - margin - iconWidth
                    iconRight = itemView.right - margin
                } else {
                    background = ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                }
                background.draw(c)
                icon?.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom)
                icon?.draw(c)
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I need to swipe it programmatically by half to one and then to other direction as part of the tutorial.
I found a simple solution and it works, but it totally ignores my background/icon drawing from the code above:

```
var x = viewItem?.itemView?.findViewById<View>(R.id.rune_row_background)
x.animate().translationX(x.width /2f).setDuration(1000)
```

Can someone please advice how can I force this 2 pieces to work together. Or a better way to mimic swipe so it would respect ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback object defined.
I am new to android Dev, so probably can miss something obvious.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution proposed by Oleh in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253518/14569782

However during implementation I found out that the code is not applicable when recyclerView is not constrained directly to the top of the screen. So we get child absolute coordinates of the child and apply them as relative coordinated to recyclerView. As a result - we shift our Y by distance between top of the screen and top of the recyclerView.

To solve it I have modified previous solution:

```
private fun swipeRecyclerViewItem(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        index: Int,
        distance: Int,
        direction: Int,
        time: Long
    ) {
        val childView = recyclerView.getChildAt(index) ?: return
        val x = childView.width / 2F
        val viewLocation = IntArray(2)
        val parentLocation = IntArray(2)
        childView.getLocationInWindow(viewLocation)
        recyclerView.getLocationInWindow(parentLocation)
        val y = (viewLocation[1] - parentLocation[1] + childView.height) / 2F
        val downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(
            MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                downTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                x,
                y,
                0
            )
        )
        ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, distance).apply {
            duration = time
            addUpdateListener {
                val dX = it.animatedValue as Int
                val mX = when (direction) {
                    ItemTouchHelper.END -> x + dX
                    ItemTouchHelper.START -> x - dX
                    else -> 0F
                }
                recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(
                    MotionEvent.obtain(
                        downTime,
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
                        mX,
                        y,
                        0
                    )
                )
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

Comment: The wrong item is swiped in both cases in Oleh's answer and yours also